# PHP format string to numbers seperated by two decimal points

Tags: php, string, format, decimalformat

User can input values in following format:

- 1.00
- 1
- 1,00

Now I need to return this values formated by using two decimal points (,). When I use:

number_format($request->amount, 2, ',','')

And use "1,00" as input I get this error:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

What's the best way to solve this and still be able to handle all three types of input?

Here's a short example:

```
input of user:|output:
1.00           1,00
1              1,00 
1,51           1,51
```

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question here but I don't believe you can use a comma in a numeric value. You can use a decimal point ( . ) like your first input value in the example above. Why are you using a comma instead?

Comment: user input value with comma??

Comment: Many locale's reverse the usage of ',' and '.' in numbers, i.e., use a comma to separate the whole and decimal portions of a number.  For more details than you possible want to know, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$request->amount = str_replace(",", ".", $request->amount);
number_format($request->amount, 2, ',','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
number_format((int)$request->amount, 2, ',','');
```

Comment: By converting $request->amount to an integer, you'll lose the numbers following a decimal place or comma so the above will not work. For example: If I passed 1,51 or 1.51 to this, it would output 1,00.