# PHP generate cent value of entered amount

Tags: php, formatting, int

In my database I store the amount of a user in cents.
Now I need to convert user input to integer.

input of user(string) :|output (int):
1.00                     100
1                        100
1,51                     151

I have no idea, how to solve this. Formatting amounts like: 1.00 and 1,00 isn't a big problem, but what's the best way to format the amount like "1" to the right amount of cents?
What I use at the moment (**not working with inputs like "1"**):

```
       $value = intval(str_replace([',','.'],'', $request->amount));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP format string to numbers seperated by two decimal points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923007/php-format-string-to-numbers-seperated-by-two-decimal-points)

Comment: No, no duplicate, here I need to do some calculation and get int values, no strings. Please read complete question.

Comment: How did you mean this? Hope you understand what I try to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about casting as a float and multiplying by 100?

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/plain");

$x = '1,51';
$x = (float) str_replace(',','.', $x);
echo (int) ($x * 100)."\n";

$x = '1';
$x = (float) str_replace(',','.', $x);
echo (int) ($x * 100)."\n";

$x = '1.51';
$x = (float) str_replace(',','.', $x);
echo (int) ($x * 100)."\n";

$x = '1,00';
$x = (float) str_replace(',','.', $x);
echo (int) ($x * 100)."\n";

$x = '1.00';
$x = (float) str_replace(',','.', $x);
echo (int) ($x * 100)."\n";
```

returns:

```
151
100
151
100
100
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way without "filtering/switching" for each "input variation". Think you understand my need.

Comment: you will have to catch all of those commas and replace with "." so they can be read as decimals.

Comment: yes, try a str_replace will replace a comma if it exists, and do nothing if not.

Answer (score 0):

str_replace should be used with two arrays or two strings

```
       $value = intval(str_replace([',','.'],['',''], $request->amount));
```